# One remote mongos vs many local ones

Tags: mongodb, replication

Until now I have used one mongos per physical server, but I am wondering, if I could save some resources by having all traffic redirected to only one remote/central mongos.

Is this considered less stable, provided I have one more failover?

Talking about 10s of clients connecting ~10k times per minute.
ulimit/maxConns is set to 20000 though I do not think that I will need it since even with 100 clients à 5 conns that are only 500 connections.

Comment: This question is more suited to another site in the Stack Exchange network dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @chridam Yes it is. But before the OP does that there would be a [duplicate question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/92117/mongodb-co-locate-the-mongos-process-on-application-servers/93874#93874) to this even there.

Comment: Thank you for the link - that helped. I voted for close now too. Should I delete this question or should it stay for others to find?